# Unreal Engine 4 Spawn Emitter At Character Location

Tags: location, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am currently trying to get a particle effect to spawn when the character hits a surface, depending on the surface a different particle effect is chosen. I have included a picture of my BP for my character Animation. Currently the particle effect spawns but only in one place and does not follow the character as it moves. So every time i step on a surface the particle effect happens at the spawn  location. I have followed and looked at many threads and videos already to get to this point, any help would be greatly appreciated, I am using UE4 4.9.2, thank you.

[image: CharacterAnim BluePrint]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you would achieve the desired results by plugging in the actor location, into the 'Location' input of the 'Spawn Emitter At Location' node.

What you are doing right now is, tracing from (0, 0, 0) to the actor location, seeing if there is a collision, and then using this location of the collision to spawn the emitter.

I'm surprised that it even works quite honestly.

Take heart though! The use of the trace test for the Surface Type check is completely accurate.

What I would modify in the trace test is to plug in the actor location in both the start and end inputs, with the end input being a location that is offset in the Negative Z direction by your actor height. This will take some trial and error. What this would do is trace from the actor to the plane beneath the actor.

However, if the spawning works correctly as it is right now, perhaps the above change is not necessary.

**TL;DR:**

Simply use the Actor Location node to provide the location for the emitter to spawn, perhaps with an offset to make sure it spawns at the feet location, and you will be golden!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have the start of your line be somewhere other than 0,0,0. For example, have the trace start at the player and shoot it downwards to check the surface type. Message back if you need further help!